# Can Mockito stub a method without regard to the argument?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to test some legacy code, using Mockito.

I want to stub a `FooDao` that is used in production as follows:

```
foo = fooDao.getBar(new Bazoo());
```

I can write:

```
when(fooDao.getBar(new Bazoo())).thenReturn(myFoo);
```

But the obvious problem is that `getBar()` is never called with the same `Bazoo` object that I stubbed the method for. (Curse that `new` operator!)

I would love it if I could stub the method in a way that it returns `myFoo` regardless of the argument. Failing that, I'll listen to other workaround suggestions, but I'd really like to avoid changing the production code until there is reasonable test coverage.

Answer (score 540, accepted):

```
when(
  fooDao.getBar(
    any(Bazoo.class)
  )
).thenReturn(myFoo);
```

or (to avoid `null`s):

```
when(
  fooDao.getBar(
    (Bazoo)notNull()
  )
).thenReturn(myFoo);
```

Don't forget to import matchers (many others are available):

For Mockito 2.1.0 and newer:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;
```

For older versions:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
```

Comment: I love it when the answer precedes the end of the 'accept answer freeze'.

Comment: There's a `notNull(Bazoo.class)` just like the `any(Bazoo.class)` (maybe it didn't exist at the time of this answer)

Comment: i had a slightly special situation where i could have either of two possible arguments - `Bazoo` or `Cazoo` which are both subclasses of, say, `Azoo`. for `Bazoo` i needed to return `foo`, but for `Cazoo` i needed to return `bar`. in this situation the proposed `Matchers.any()` solution doesn't work, however, `Matchers.isA()` works perfect.

Comment: `org.mockito.Matchers` is now deprecated - use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers` instead, i.e. `import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*` (see [docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Matchers.html))

Comment: `when(myFoo.knowsWhatsUp()).thenReturn(myMoney);`

Comment: For some reason I do not understand, in my case Eclipse only imports the `any` method from the `CoreMatchers` package. I had to manually add the import statement from the `ArgumentMatchers` package.

Comment: `notNull` seems to be deprecated. You can use `ArgumentMatchers.isNotNull()`.

Answer (score 24):

http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html

`anyObject()` should fit your needs.

Also, you can always consider implementing `hashCode()` and `equals()` for the `Bazoo` class. This would make your code example work the way you want.

Comment: Agreed with second suggestion, but I'm still opting to not do that for non-technical reasons.

Comment: The Matchers class is deprecated (see [docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Matchers.html) - _"This class will likely be removed in version 3.0"_)

Comment: @JohannesRabauer I guess it should be changed to `any()` ?

Comment: @golimar it looks like this does the exact same thing. `any()` and `anyObject()` are the same, according to the docs linked above.  However the complete `Matchers` class is deprecated and the class `ArgumentMatchers` should be used instead.

Answer (score 18):

Use like this:

```
when(
  fooDao.getBar(
    Matchers.<Bazoo>any()
  )
).thenReturn(myFoo);
```

Before you need to import `Mockito.Matchers`

Comment: This is depricated!

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to rely on good old fashion `equals` method.  As long as the argument in the `when` mock `equals` the argument in the code being tested, then Mockito will match the mock.

Here is an example.

```
public class MyPojo {

    public MyPojo( String someField ) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    private String someField;

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object o ) {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        MyPojo myPojo = ( MyPojo ) o;
        return someField.equals( myPojo.someField );
    }

}
```

then, assuming you know what the value for `someField` will be, you can mock it like this.

```
when(fooDao.getBar(new MyPojo(expectedSomeField))).thenReturn(myFoo);
```

pros:  This is more explicit then `any` matchers.  As a reviewer of code, I keep an eye open for `any` in the code junior developers write, as it glances over their code's logic to generate the appropriate object being passed.

con:  Sometimes the field being passed to the object is a random ID.  For this case you cannot easily construct the expected argument object in your mock code.

Another possible approach is to use Mockito's `Answer` object that can be used with the `when` method.  `Answer` lets you intercept the actual call and inspect the input argument and return a mock object.  In the example below I am using `any` to catch any request to the method being mocked.  But then in the `Answer` lambda, I can further inspect the Bazo argument... maybe to verify that a proper ID was passed to it.  I prefer this over `any` by itself so that at least some inspection is done on the argument.

```
    Bar mockBar = //generate mock Bar.

    when(fooDao.getBar(any(Bazo.class))
    .thenAnswer(  ( InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) -> {
        Bazo actualBazo = invocationOnMock.getArgument( 0 );

        //inspect the actualBazo here and thrw exception if it does not meet your testing requirements.
        return mockBar;
    } );
```

So to sum it all up, I like relying on `equals` (where the expected argument and actual argument should be equal to each other) and if equals is not possible (due to not being able to predict the actual argument's state), I'll resort to `Answer` to inspect the argument.

Comment: Thanks for the example of how to get the argument.