# Any Value Mockito Test Java

Tags: java, testing, mocking, arguments, mockito

```
String parserRes [] = {"right9"};
when(mockedParser.parse("whatever")).thenReturn(parserRes);
board = boardMaker.makeBoardFrom("whatever");
```

I'm using mockito an the argument of the method `parse` do not matter because whatever is passed in "right9" will always be the returning argument. 
The same thing applies to `makeBoardFrom`since it uses the `parse` method. How do I replace that "whatever" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969630/can-mockito-stub-a-method-without-regard-to-the-argument

Answer (score 1):

```
when(mockedParser.parse(Matchers.anyString())).thenReturn(parserRes);
```

should do the trick. See [here](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html) for more info