# Mocking return with any passed argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

While trying to mock MavenXpp3Reader the `read()` method remains null despite my attempts to mock the return. Here is my attempt

```
    String testVer = "1.0.0.TEST";
    MavenXpp3Reader mockReader = mock(MavenXpp3Reader.class);
    Model mockModel = mock(Model.class);
    when(mockModel.getVersion()).thenReturn(testVer);
    when(mockReader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"))).thenReturn(mockModel);

    Model model = mockReader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
```

`model` remains null. Basically, I want to return `mockModel` whenever `MavenXpp3Reader.read()` is called, no matter what arguments are passed.

Comment: [Can Mockito stub a method without regard to the argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969630/can-mockito-stub-a-method-without-regard-to-the-argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `any()` from Mockito framework instead of `(new FileReader("pom.xml"))`

For example:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

...
when(mockReader.read(any(Reader.class)).thenReturn(mockModel);
...
```

Comment: Your general idea is correct. But here `any()` cannot work here because `read()` is overloaded. So the invocation will be considered as ambiguous by the compiler.

Comment: Much better now.

Answer (score 3):

> Basically, I want to return mockModel whenever MavenXpp3Reader.read()
>   is called, no matter what arguments are passed.

You could use `Mockito.any()` in the mock recording but it will not compile because `MavenXpp3Reader.read()` is overloaded.
You should so specify the class matching to a specific overload :

```
when(mockReader.read(Mockito.any(Reader.class))).thenReturn(mockModel);
```

But in most of case you want to avoid any matcher because that is not strict enough.

---

About your mock recording :

```
when(mockReader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"))).thenReturn(mockModel);
```

will not be used here :

```
Model model = mockReader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
```

because the way which you specify the `FileReader` argument (without a soft argument matcher) makes Mockito to rely  on the `equals()` method of the classes to consider the match and `new FileReader("pom.xml").equals(new FileReader("pom.xml"))` returns `false` as `FileReader` doesn't override `equals()`.
But it will work :

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("pom.xml")
when(mockReader.read(reader)).thenReturn(mockModel);
Model model = mockReader.read(reader);
```

Comment: I think question about a bit different thing: **I want to return mockModel whenever MavenXpp3Reader.read() is called, no matter what arguments are passed**